# How to align buttons horizontally?

Tags: python, html, css, django, button

I'm trying to figure out how to make buttons to be horizontally instead of vertically.

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Register
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<form action="/registration/customer/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <button style="font-size : 30px;width:350px;height:300px;" type="submit" name="type" value="customer"
            class="btn btn-success">Zákazník
    </button>

</form>
<form action="/registration/freelancer/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <button style="font-size : 30px;width:350px;height:300px;" type="submit" name="type" value="freelancer"
            class="btn btn-success">Predajca
    </button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

There are two buttons, each button should run different `view`. I want to make them side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using css style like

```
form {
  display:inline;
}
```

this will display the form inline with their buttton (adjust the screen wider and you will see the results)

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/8agtkr30/

Answer (score 0):

In your `btn` CSS class you should add `text-align: center`.

If it doesn't work, check that your form's width is 100%, because it will align depending on your form's size.